# Calculating retention rate per month, using start and end dates

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, lubridate

I have a dataset that looks like the one below (but with many tens of thousands of rows). I have an ID number, and a start and end date. I need to calculate **retention rate per month**.

I am defining retention rate as: (Total # patients at end of the month - # Patients that started treatment during the month)/(Total # Patients at the start of the month).

How would I do this in R using e.g. dplyr?

```
df <- data.frame(patient_ID= c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"),
                 treatment_start_date = as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2014-04-01",
                                   "2019-04-01", "2020-04-01")),
                 treatment_end_date = as.Date(c("2014-12-31", "2017-03-31", "2018-03-31", "2019-03-31", 
                                 "2020-03-31", "2021-04-30")))
```

Comment: how do you derive the information "Patients that newly arrived to treatment during the month" from your data?

Comment: We know the date they enter treatment (treatment_start_date)

Comment: What is the expected output for the data shared here?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to have summarized the average treatment time per month. If not, please be more specific with the desired output. Look at the code below.

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(2017)
options(digits=4)


df <- data.frame(patient_ID= c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"),
                 treatment_start_date = as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2014-04-01",
                                                  "2019-04-01", "2020-04-01")),
                 treatment_end_date = as.Date(c("2014-12-31", "2017-03-31", "2018-03-31", "2019-03-31", 
                                                "2020-03-31", "2021-04-30")))


df$days <- as.Date(df$treatment_end_date, format="%Y/%m/%d") -
  as.Date(df$treatment_start_date, format="%Y/%m/%d")

df_per_month <- df %>%  group_by(month=floor_date(treatment_start_date, "month")) %>%
  summarise(mean_month=mean(days))
```

Is this what you had in mind? the average treatment period in days is calculated for the start of the treatment.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I understand what you want:

- Number of patients receiving treatment at the end of each month
- Number of patients who started treatment during each month
- Number of patients receiving treatment at the start of each month*

*Does this include patients who started treatment on the first day of the month (eg everyone in your sample data)? - I have assumed it does in this example.

So, load your sample data and make sure the dates are in proper `date` format

```
df <- data.frame(patient_ID= c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"),
                 treatment_start_date = as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2014-04-01",
                                                  "2019-04-01", "2020-04-01")),
                 treatment_end_date = as.Date(c("2014-12-31", "2017-03-31", "2018-03-31", "2019-03-31", 
                                                "2020-03-31", "2021-04-30")))

# make sure the dates are date format
df %>% 
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(across(treatment_start_date:treatment_end_date, ~ymd(.))) %>% 
  {. ->> df_1}

df_1

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# patient_ID treatment_start_date treatment_end_date
# <chr>      <date>               <date>            
# AA         2004-01-01           2014-12-31        
# BB         2007-01-01           2017-03-31        
# CC         2012-04-01           2018-03-31        
# DD         2014-04-01           2019-03-31        
# EE         2019-04-01           2020-03-31        
# FF         2020-04-01           2021-04-30
```

Then, we make a sequence of every single date each patient was receiving treatment on (start and end dates inclusive).

```
# make a sequence of every date a patient was in the treatment
df_1 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(
    treatment_days = list(seq(treatment_start_date, treatment_end_date, by = 'day'))
  ) %>% 
  select(patient_ID, treatment_days) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c('treatment_days')) %>% 
  {. ->> df_2}

df_2

# # A tibble: 12,539 x 2
# patient_ID treatment_days
# <chr>      <date>        
# AA         2004-01-01    
# AA         2004-01-02    
# AA         2004-01-03    
# AA         2004-01-04    
# AA         2004-01-05    
# AA         2004-01-06    
# AA         2004-01-07    
# AA         2004-01-08    
# AA         2004-01-09    
# AA         2004-01-10    
# # ... with 12,529 more rows
```

Then, we work out how many patients were in treatment each day, and keep just the first and last days of each month.

```
df_2 %>% 
  
  # work out how many patients were in treatment for each day
  group_by(treatment_days) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_patients = n_distinct(patient_ID)
  ) %>% 
  
  # make month column
  mutate(
    month = format(treatment_days, format = '%Y-%m')
  ) %>% 
  
  # keep only the first and last days of each month
  group_by(month) %>% 
  filter(
    day(treatment_days) == 1 | day(treatment_days) == max(day(treatment_days))
  ) %>% 
  
  # determine number of patients at the start and end of each month
  #    ensure the dates are in order
  arrange(month, treatment_days) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_patient_start = nth(n_patients, 1), 
    n_patient_end = nth(n_patients, 2), 
  ) %>% 
  
  {. ->> df_3}

df_3

# # A tibble: 208 x 3
# month   n_patient_start n_patient_end
# <chr>             <int>         <int>
# 2004-01               1             1
# 2004-02               1             1
# 2004-03               1             1
# 2004-04               1             1
# 2004-05               1             1
# 2004-06               1             1
# 2004-07               1             1
# 2004-08               1             1
# 2004-09               1             1
# 2004-10               1             1
# # ... with 198 more rows
```

So, now we have the total number of patients receiving treatment at the start and end of each month.

Before we calculate retention rate, we need to know how many patients started their treatment in each month, so this can be used in your retention rate calculation.

```
# how many patients started each month?
df_1 %>% 
  select(patient_ID, treatment_start_date) %>% 
  mutate(
    month = format(treatment_start_date, format = '%Y-%m')
  ) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_starting_patients = n_distinct(patient_ID)
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> n_new_per_month}

n_new_per_month

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
# month   n_starting_patients
# <chr>                 <int>
# 2004-01                   1
# 2007-01                   1
# 2012-04                   1
# 2014-04                   1
# 2019-04                   1
# 2020-04                   1
```

We combine the number of starting patients with the number of active patients for the start and end of each month. Then, we can calculate retention rate as described by the formula in your question.

```
# now, we join in new patients per month
df_3 %>% 
  left_join(n_new_per_month) %>% 
  mutate(
    n_starting_patients = ifelse(is.na(n_starting_patients), 0, n_starting_patients)
  ) %>% 
  
  # calculate retention rate
  mutate(
    ret_rate = (n_patient_end - n_starting_patients) / n_patient_start
  )

# # A tibble: 208 x 5
# month   n_patient_start n_patient_end n_starting_patients ret_rate
# <chr>             <int>         <int>               <dbl>    <dbl>
# 2004-01               1             1                   1        0
# 2004-02               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-03               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-04               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-05               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-06               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-07               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-08               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-09               1             1                   0        1
# 2004-10               1             1                   0        1
# # ... with 198 more rows
```

Now I'm not too sure if this is correct, because for example in the preview above - we have a retention rate of `0` for Jan 2004, even though no patients were lost during this month (in fact we had one start treatment). This is because patient AA started on Jan 1st, so retention rate was calculated as `(number of patients at the end of the month - number of patients that started in that month) / number of patients at the start of the month`, or `(1 - 1) / 1` = `0 / 1` = `0`.

Things that will influence retention rate with the current formula:

- Are start and end dates included in the dates a patient is receiving treatment?
- If a patient starts on the 1st day of the month, does this mean they are included or removed from the 'patients *at* the start of the month'? I can understand if you wanted to remove number of patients that started during the middle of the month, but it doesn't quite make sense to me with the current formula.